# "We, who've been connected by blood to Prussia's throne and people since Düppel"

Tags: 19th-century, germany, prussia, denmark

I was listening to an old German song on Youtube and [heard](https://youtu.be/Fzt9qoemCeE?t=226) the following mysterious lines:

> wir, die seit Düppel durch des Blutes Bande
>
> an Preußens Thron und Volk gekettet sind

My translation of these lines into English is in the title of this post, and I am puzzled as to what historical reference they make.

Of course, I know that Düppel is the German name for Dybbøl, a Danish town at which Prussia fought two battles, one during the First Schleswig War and one during the Second Schleswig War, but the song was written before those wars. At least, Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preu%C3%9Fenlied) that the song was the national Prussian anthem from 1830 to 1840, while the [First Schleswig War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Schleswig_War) broke out in 1848.

And even if these lines were about a battle, they wouldn't make sense to me, for I can't imagine how a battle might have resulted in a blood connection to Prussia's throne and people.

So, what are these mysterious lines about?

Comment: Curiously, the supposedly complete (six stanza) version of the Preußenlied in the German Wikipedia does not contain these lyrics. The German Wikipedia mentions that the author, who died in 1855, last made alterations to the lyrics in 1851, but these are unrelated to the cited lyrics. Could this be a third party addition to the song? If so, by whom and when?

Comment: Interesting. Searching google books for "seit Düppel durch des Blutes Bande" (with quotation marks) yields two pages with results, apparently mostly from Skandinavian authors. "Wo Fürst und Volk sich reichen so die Hand", another line from the same song, yields 14 pages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the book "[Before, during and after 1914](https://archive.org/stream/beforeduringafte00nystuoft/beforeduringafte00nystuoft_djvu.txt)" by [Anton Kristen Nyström](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton_Nystr%C3%B6m), London 1915, p.73/74, emphasis mine:

> A German song-book (Liederbuch) was introduced in 1884 into Schleswig schools by an order of the Government, and it was directed that the school-children should learn at least twenty of its songs by heart. Of these twenty
> songs, twelve are German national or war songs, and it may be of interest to note that amongst them is the famous Preussenlied "Ich bin ein Preusse." But
> this historical inexactitude was not enough. The song consisted originally of five verses, but for the benefit of the Schleswigers **a sixth verse, by Privy Councillor Schneider (a German immigrant), was added in 1869**. This verse runs as follows :

> Und wir, die wir am[sic!] Ost- und Nordensee als Wacht gestellt,
> gestählt von Wog und Wind, wir, die Seit[sic!] Düppel durch des Blutes
> Bande an Preussens Thron and Volk gekettet sind, wir woll'n nicht
> rückwarts schauen, nein vorwärts mit Vertrauen ! Wir rufen's
> laut in alle Welt hinein : "Auch wir sind Preussen, wollen Preussen
> sein!"

> The following is a literal prose translation of this verse :

> And we, posted as sentinels on Baltic and North Sea,
> hardened by wave and wind, we who since the Duppel
> fight have been tied by bonds of blood to Prussia's throne
> and people, we will not look back, nay, forward, and with
> confidence ! We cry aloud that all the world may hear :
> "We too are Prussians, and Prussians want to be!"

Not sure how accurate this is, but it might be a starting point for further research.

(found via google books search for "seit Düppel durch des Blutes Bande". Note that the first line, apart from slightly strange grammar, is also subtly different from the version on English wikipedia)

---

Addendum: The English wp article says that the seventh stanza was added by an author named "Schneider"(!) in 1851 (note the same name as in the book cited above, even though it is a common name). While the German article says the sixth stanza of the shorter German version was added by the original author, Thiersch, in 1851.

Wikipedia commons has a scan from an oldish-German songbook ([part 1](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Allgemeines_Deutsches_Kommersbuch:30), [part 2](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Allgemeines_Deutsches_Kommersbuch:31)) which gives a rather strong impression that the text originally had five stanzas, that the stanza added in 1851 is not about Schleswig, and that that 1851 stanza was quite possibly written by Thiersch himself.

I think a plausible scenario is that English wp authors are confused because that Schleswig stanza was inserted before the last Stanza that Thiersch wrote, so that we now have two sixth stanzas (one written by Thiersch, and a different one about Schleswig).

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, the lines may indeed be about a battle at Dybbøl, after all. But what could the meaning of "connected by blood" be?

Comment: Probably means that they fought together? The other possible explanation would be that they have common ancestors, but then "since Düppel" would not make much sense.

Comment: So, it's like, "We share the same blood on our hands"? Blood of the same enemy? I just can't understand how fighting together means a blood connection

Comment: It sounds like that verse was government propaganda, so it was more about making people believe something than reflecting what people believe(d). The "logic" goes like "We are Prussians, we share the same blood" and "Düppel proved that we are Prussians".

Comment: @Mitsuko Isn't "bleeding together" a rather common rhetorical idea for claiming people who fought together should feel a bond? I would read a "blood connection" forged in battle as much more likely to be about "our" blood than "the enemy's" blood. (i.e. "We both suffered in the same struggle, fighting for a common cause").

Comment: @Mitsuko: Düppel was the place of strategically important entrenchments, the "Düppeler Schanzen". It belonged to the Duchy of Schleswig, in turn part of the then multi-ethnical state of Denmark. As such it had seen battle before the 1864 conquest which settled the German-Danish war over Schleswig - including an 1849 engagement between both parties. So, the "we, too [sic], are Prussians" of the 1851 addition might well allude to the choice of military ("blood bonded") allegiance in the mounting conflict.

Comment: @I_O the stanza added in 1851. does not seem to be about Schleswig, see the scan at wiki commons. (again, at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/De_Schauenburg_Allgemeines_Deutsches_Kommersbuch_031.jpg)

Comment: @Jan: back then, Düppel (Danish: Dybbøl), was part of Schleswig and place of the pivotal battle that won the Prussian[sic]-Austrian "German Confederation" the 2nd Schleswig War: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dybb%C3%B8l

Comment: @I_O According to the scan I already linked to above, the stanza added in 1851 starts with "Des Preußen Stern soll weithin hell erglänzen" and does not contain the word "Düppel". You can look it up yourself at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/De_Schauenburg_Allgemeines_Deutsches_Kommersbuch_031.jpg .

Comment: Slightly more useful lnk: https://de.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Allgemeines_Deutsches_Kommersbuch:31 . That page contains the sixth stanza of the song, and the name of the author. The first five stanzas are at https://de.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Allgemeines_Deutsches_Kommersbuch:30